# How to pass column names as Input from other List and refer other data.table to sum scores?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.table(s) DT1 and RF, where DT1 is master table and RF is crosswalk for variables value.

```
 DT1 <- data.table(id = c(1:10),Var1=c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0) ,Var2=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1), 
              Var3=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0),Var4=c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
              Var5=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0))
 RF <- data.table (Variable = c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4","Var5","Var6","Var7","Var8",
              "Var9","Var10"), 
              CO = c(1.1,2.3,1.4,1.5,1.0,3.8,2.5,3.7,2.1,2.0), 
              IN = c(2.1,1.3,1.9,2.5,1.7,2.8,2.9,1.7,1.1,2.0))
```

I want to calculate a Score column for model CO and IN in DT1 which is additive and will take different variables as input for both the models. For that I have created lists of variables for both models:

```
 List1 <- c("Var1","Var3","Var5")
 List2 <- c("Var1","Var2","Var6","Var7","Var8")
```

So if I am calculating Score_CO then my Function should check in List1 for Variables. Like for each row in DT1 it should check if

```
 1) Var1 == 1, If yes, 
 2) then check for that in RF for RF$Variable == Var1, if yes
 3) get RF$CO value, 
 4) else return (0)
```

I have tried two methods yet:

```
 METHOD 1:
 L1<- length(List1)
 y<-0
 DT1 <-DT1[,Score_CO:={for(i in 1:L1){
             x<-parse(text = List1[i])
             if(DT1[,eval(x)] == 1){
             x<-RF[which(RF[,'Variable'] == List1[i],),CO]}
             else{as.numeric(0.0)}
             y=y+x }
             return(y)}]

 METHOD 2:
 Score_Calc<-function(DT,RF, List, model = 'CO'){
 pvar<- 0
 pvar<-for(i in 1:nrow(DT)){
 for(j in 1:length(List)){
  x<-parse(text = List[j])  
  ifelse(DT[i,eval(x)] == 1, RF[which(RF[,'Variable'] == List[j],),model], 0)
 }
 pvar <- pvar + pvar
 DT[,paste0('Score_',model):= pvar]
 }
 return(DT)
 }

 Score_Calc(DT=DT1,RF = RF, List=List1, model = 'CO')
```

But I am not getting the result. Output should be:

```
 OUTPUT:
  id    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Score_CO
   1    1   0   1   1   0   2.5
   2    0   0   1   1   0   1.4
   3    0   0   1   0   0   1.4
   4    0   0   0   0   0   0
   5    1   1   0   1   1   2.1
   6    0   0   0   0   0   0
   7    1   1   1   0   1   3.5
   8    1   0   1   0   1   3.5
   9    0   0   0   0   0   0
  10    0   1   0   0   0   0
```

P.S.: Score_CO = Var1 + Var2 + Var3 (Values from RF table CO column)

Please have a look and help me finding what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a matrix multiplication version:

```
as.matrix(DT1[, -1, with=F]) %*% as.matrix(RF[1:5, -1, with=F])
#        CO  IN
#  [1,] 4.0 6.5
#  [2,] 2.9 4.4
#  [3,] 1.4 1.9
#  [4,] 0.0 0.0
#  [5,] 5.9 7.6
#  [6,] 0.0 0.0
#  [7,] 5.8 7.0
#  [8,] 3.5 5.7
#  [9,] 0.0 0.0
# [10,] 2.3 1.3
```

---

data.table version 1.  Just be careful, once you set the key for RF, the matrix multiplication will give you a different answer as setting key reorders it

EDIT: an alternate that does both calculations:

```
setkey(RF, Variable)
fun <- function(DT, col) sum(RF[names(DT), ][, col, with=F] * unlist(DT))
DT1[,list(CO=fun(.SD, "CO"), IN=fun(.SD, "IN")), by=id]
#     id  CO  IN
#  1:  1 4.0 6.5
#  2:  2 2.9 4.4
#  3:  3 1.4 1.9
#  4:  4 0.0 0.0
#  5:  5 5.9 7.6
#  6:  6 0.0 0.0
#  7:  7 5.8 7.0
#  8:  8 3.5 5.7
#  9:  9 0.0 0.0
# 10: 10 2.3 1.3
```

---

OLD VERSION:

Here is a potential solution for calculating `CO`.  You can easily extend this to do `IN`.  Basically, what we do is multiply the values in DT1 by their corresponding RF values, and then add those:

```
setkey(RF, Variable)
DT2 <- DT1[, c(
  list(id=id),
  sapply(
    names(.SD[, -1, with=F]), 
    function(x) unlist(.SD[, x, with = F] * RF[x, ][, CO]),
    simplify=F
  )
) ][, CO:=apply(.SD[, -1, with=F], 1, sum)]
DT2
#     id Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5  CO
#  1:  1  1.1  0.0  1.4  1.5    0 4.0
#  2:  2  0.0  0.0  1.4  1.5    0 2.9
#  3:  3  0.0  0.0  1.4  0.0    0 1.4
#  4:  4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0 0.0
#  5:  5  1.1  2.3  0.0  1.5    1 5.9
#  6:  6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0 0.0
#  7:  7  1.1  2.3  1.4  0.0    1 5.8
#  8:  8  1.1  0.0  1.4  0.0    1 3.5
#  9:  9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0 0.0
# 10: 10  0.0  2.3  0.0  0.0    0 2.3
```

The first `sapply` loops through every `Var#` column in the data table, finding the corresponding value from the `CO` in `RF`, and multiplies the column by that value (this produces the modified `Var1-5` values you see above.  The `CO:=apply(...` bit just calculates the sum of `Var1-5` for each row and saves them as a `CO` column in `DT2`.

Comment: Thanks it looks good, I just wanted to ask how I can just get the subset of DT1 with variables which are in List1. Because for CO I just want to check variables which are in List 1 (Var1, Var3, Var5) and add them.

Comment: @nsDataSci, if this answers your question, please consider marking it as answered by clicking the checkbox.  Thanks.

Comment: Ofcourse, Thanks so much.... I was about to do so.With the solution you gave and I just added a step that I subset the data with columns corresponds to list and then apply your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I can't vote up this solution because it says it needs more than 15 reputation. But I really want to vote up this.

Comment: @nsDataSci, don't worry about it.  This comment is good enough.  Thanks!